# Stop Asp.Net Core tag helpers formatting numbers

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have the situation when the asp-for formats my output, I put 5 but it displays me "5,00":

[image]

As I am in France, it puts the comas, and then does not validate the input (because of format I suppose).

Is there a way to stop asp.net formatting my numbers - leave 5 as is, no neeed to add something to it.

```
<label asp-for="X" class="control-label"></label>
<input asp-for="X" class="form-control" />
<span asp-validation-for="X" class="text-danger"></span>
```

I added

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
public decimal X { get; set; }
```

but this does not help.

I need to use decimals in my fields, but why it does put the comas by itself, then says "invalid format"?

Answer (score 1):

DisplayFormat is considered when you use Html.DisplayFor, I don't know a way how is possible to enforce a number to be in a specific format it you are not changing it yourself to string, or maybe there is..

Another approach is to change the culture, US or invariant

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture =CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            return View();
        }
```

or in view (not very fancy)

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
Html.DisplayFor(model => model.whatever)
```

Still I don't think this solved the decimals problem, it will be 4.00 instead of 4,00

If you don't want decimals, on view model use int instead or decimal

Comment: I use tag helpers; not "DisplayFor" , do you think DisplayFor instead of "asp-for"  will help to sole the problem?

Comment: no, it won't, I mean in your example input asp-for="X" is in fact and Html.EditorFor, that is doing similar things for as DisplayFor with DisplayFormat, you can try on a date time as example to understand is working, and it will, But as I said I don't think you can display a decimal as a non decimal, and you shouldn't, what if you have a decimal with decimals on the object rendered in view? what then? So best you can do is to enforce a Invariant culture or to use int instead of decimal